# How to make post request to Content-Type text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8

Tags: python

I am beginner in python. I would like to parse a website but the header shows the content type `text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8` and the request payload...

```
7|0|4|https://kekeke.cc/com.liquable.hiroba.home.gwt.HomeModule/|53263EDF7F9313FDD5BD38B49D3A7A77|com.liquable.hiroba.gwt.client.square.IGwtSquareService|getNoOfCrowd|1|2|3|4|0|
```

Request:

```
POST /com.liquable.hiroba.gwt.server.GWTHandler/squareService HTTP/1.1
Host: kekeke.cc
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: zh-TW,zh;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://kekeke.cc/
Content-Type: text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8
X-GWT-Permutation: 8F22796231EB8C8312C5D1BB10451262
X-GWT-Module-Base: https://kekeke.cc/com.liquable.hiroba.home.gwt.HomeModule/
Content-Length: 177
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

Can anyone tell me how to make post request in python?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It can be solved by simply using r = requests.post(url, "7|0|4|https://kekeke.cc/com.liquable.hiroba.home.gwt.HomeModule/|53263EDF7F9313FDD5BD38B49D3A7A77|com.liquable.hiroba.gwt.client.square.IGwtSquareService|getNoOfCrowd|1|2|3|4|0|", headers=headers). In many online tutorials, they teach the post request by using data in form of {data:data} to submit post request only. However, it can be done by submitting data in form of string in some cases.